# Underscore using multiple functions in one line

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, mixins

I have the following code:

```
function doSomething(str){
    return str+="a";
}

function anotherFunction(str){
    return str+="b";
}

_.mixin({
    doSomething:doSomething,
    anotherFunction:anotherFunction
});
```

I want to use multiple functions together in one line, but I can't manage to work:

`var output=_("startingtext").doSomething().anotherFunction();`

I managed to make it work using `_.chain`, but I am not sure if chain should be used because in their [example](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#chain) they are using with objects and stuff, so I really doubt this is the way to go for string manipulation.

Sorry, I am new to underscore :(, any help is appreciated.

Comment: you would have to wrap any output again with _(), eg `return _(str+"a");` in the first function and equivalent in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_.chain()` is exactly the way to go.

In Javascript, *everything* is an object.  Including a string.  You were doing it right the first time.  `_.chain()` wraps your string in an object that can be passed forward, chain-style, and unpacked at the end with a call to value().

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to wrap the return value with `_()` and call `.value()` at the end of the chain:

```
function a(v) {
    return _(v + 'a');
}

function b(v) {
    return _(v + 'b');
}

_.mixin({a:a, b:b});
_('some-text').a().b().value(); // returns some-textab
```

Not my favourite option though.

The accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945673/underscore-js-how-to-chain-custom-functions) has an alternative, but it still needs to call `.value()` at the end. If you really want to get rid of it, you'd have to add functions to the `String.prototype`