# Best way to replace missing/undefined values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, dictionary, underscore.js

I need to process some arrays that contains `undefined` values, like the following:

```
[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, , 1, 1 ]
[ 1, , 1, , , 1, 1 ]
[ 1, , , , , 1, 1 ]
```

What I need to achieve is **not** a removal of the `undefined` values, but I need to **replace** them with zeros.

I tried to use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) to achieve this; without success.

The following is my solution attempt:

```
binarymap = _.map(binarymap, function(curr){
    // let's replace all undefined with 0s
    if(_.isUndefined(curr)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return curr;
});
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. *underscore.js*'s function `_.map` totally ignores `undefined` values.

Any ideas? Elegant solutions?

Comment: I think you can't use the `map` function, i tried in chrome `[ 1, , , , , 1, 1 ].map(function(){console.log(arguments);});` and i only have 3x output not 8 or so

Comment: @EricG exactly, this is why I wonder if there is a good alternative

Comment: I suspect that underscore uses all the up-to-date array methods where available, and i'm pretty sure that `map`, `filter` etc all ignore `undefined` values.

Comment: If you look at the standard sections [15.4.4.19](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19) and [8.12.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.6), `Array#map` is actually expected to work that way, ignoring undefined values present in the array.

Comment: So dirty, but I had to share: `var arr = [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, , 1, 1 ];
    arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/null/g,0));`

Comment: Are there ever any other values, other than '1' or a 'hole'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to you could add the function as a mixin for use in an underscore chain. Improvised from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3946398/1377002).

```
_.mixin({
  dothis: function(obj, interceptor, context) {
    return interceptor.call(context, obj);
  }
});

function resetArray(arr) {
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === undefined) arr[i] = 0;
  }
  return arr;
}

var arr = [ 1, , , , , 1, 1 ];

_(arr)
  .chain()
  .dothis(resetArray)
  .tap(console.log) // [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/5pZGC/)

Edit: actually, there's a simpler way of doing that:

```
_.mixin({
  resetArray: function (arr) {
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === undefined) arr[i] = 0;
    }
    return arr;
  }
});

var arr = [1, , , , , 1, 1];

_(arr)
  .chain()
  .resetArray()
  .tap(console.log)
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/M3HR6/)

Comment: @francesco, I've just added an update for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 5):

The actual problem here is the [*missing array elements*](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.4),

> Array elements may be elided at the beginning, middle or end of the
>   element list. Whenever a comma in the element list is not preceded by
>   an AssignmentExpression (i.e., a comma at the beginning or after
>   another comma), the missing array element contributes to the length of
>   the Array and increases the index of subsequent elements. Elided array
>   elements are not defined. If an element is elided at the end of an
>   array, that element does not contribute to the length of the Array.

And [`Array.prototype.map`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19) skips all the missing array elements,

> callbackfn is called only for elements of the array which actually
>   exist; it is not called for missing elements of the array.

So, in order to make the Array elements to be considered by the `map` function, the simplest way I could think of is to tweak your approach a little bit, like this

```
var arr = [ 1, , , , , 1, 1 ];
console.log(_.map(Array.apply(null, arr), function (currentItem) {
    return _.isUndefined(currentItem) ? 0 : currentItem;
}));
# [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 ]
```

Here, `Array.apply` (which is actually `Function.prototype.apply`) does the important thing, converting the missing elements to `undefined`.

```
console.log(Array.apply(null, arr));
# [ 1, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 1, 1 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean..?

```
var arr = [ 1, , , , , 1, 1 ];
for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
 if( typeof(arr[i])==="undefined" ) {
  arr[i] = 9;
 }
}
console.log( arr );

// yields [1, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. But I would like to know if I can achieve an elegant solution by using *underscore.js*'s functions or similar.

Comment: This `if( arr[i] === undefined ) {...` looks better I think.

Comment: @c-smile this is some safety thing that prevents errors when someone writes `var undefined = 12`.

Comment: @francescostablum I cannot give you a more elegant solution I'm not that familiar with underscore js. I can only give you *a* solution.

Comment: @EricG In such paranoid cases you can use `var nothing = {}.nothing;` and compare it with that value. It will be more effective than string comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something changed since this was posted, but both [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) (v1.8.3) and [lodash](https://lodash.com) (v4.13.1) handle this quite well:

```
var u = [1, , , , , 1, 1];
_.map(u, function(n) { return n || 0; });

// [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Native loops skip undefined entries because they explicitly only loop over *defined elements* of an array ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description)). The source array doesn't contain `undefined` elements, it contains elements which were never defined at all.

These arrays are different:

```
[1, undefined, 1]
[1, , 1]
```

The first array defines its first index as `undefined`.
The second array does not define the first index at all.
Both have a length of 3.

This feels like it's starting to go off into the [WAT](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) fringes, but it's a subtle difference worth knowing.

Since we're in the weeds already, there is a convoluted native solution I'd never use in real life:

```
var u = [1, , , , , 1, 1];
Array(u.length).join(0).split('').map(function(n, i) { return u[i] || 0; })

// [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

`Array(u.length).join(0).split('')` yields a dummy array of arbitrary strings which can then be mapped over. The map function references the original array by index, then uses a simple boolean switch to return defined values or zero.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to remove empty elements from the array, you don't need to use underscore, just iterate over the array removing empty elements with `splice`.

You could add that feature prototyping Array class in javascript:

```
var array = [ 1, 1, , , , , 1, 1 ]; 

    Array.prototype.replaceEmptyElements = function(value) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (typeof this[i] == "undefined") {         
          this[i] = value;
        }
      }
      return this;
    };

var val = //your value
array.replaceEmptyElements(val);
```

Comment: I believe that this `array = array.filter(function() { return true; })` will be more effective for that puprpose.

Comment: @c-smile He doesnt wanna filter, he wants another value for the `undefined` values (i.e. the length should remain the same)